# Move index to the left, according to grid

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Let's say I have a grid that contains permissible and forbidden zones.

```
import numpy as np
forbidden = np.array([False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  False])
```

Now, I have a bunch of grid points between (0, 149). If they appear to be in the forbidden zone, I want to "move them to the left" until they're out of it.

For example,

```
idx = 13
forbidden[idx]  # is True, hence we want to move to the left
forbidden[5] # is False, and it is the "first index" where this is such
```

Meanwhile,

```
idx = 5
forbidden[idx] = # is False, so this index stays the way it is
```

Hence, `getCorrectIndex(13) == getCorrectIndex(5) == 5`.

An inefficient way of coding this:

```
def getCorrectIndex(idx, forbidden):
    # this trusts that the forbidden[0] == False, which is Okay
    for remove in range(0, idx):
        if not forbidden[idx - remove]:
            return idx - remove
```

A vectorized way of doing this for an array of indices would be the optimal, but I can't even come up with a proper way of doing this without that silly loop... I'd appreciate any pointer here!

Comment: what happens if the first values between 0 & 4 are `True`? and `idx` is `3`?

Comment: @HaleemurAli You can trust the first element to be `False`

Answer (score 0):

Well here's one way to do it. Not sure if you'll like it any better than your solution though.

First step, get indices of all of the `False` nodes:

```
b = np.where(forbidden == False)[0]
```

this will return

```
array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,
    37,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,
    90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102,
   103, 104, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130,
   131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136], dtype=int64)
```

After that, use `where` and `amax` again on a sliced portion of that list, to get the highest index lower than your current index. Then use that index on `b` to get the highest `False` index on the `forbidden`-array.

```
>>> index = 15
>>> first_left_false = b[np.amax(np.where(b<index))]
>>> first_left_false
5
```

The function could look something like this:

```
def getCorrectIndex(index, forbidden):
    if forbidden[index] == False:
         return index
    b = np.where(forbidden == False)[0]
    res = b[np.amax(np.where(b<index))]
    return res
```

Or if you want to pre-compute the `b` array, you could shorten it slightly:

```
def getCorrectIndex(index, b, forbidden):
     if forbidden[index] == False:
         return index
     else:
         return b[np.amax(np.where(b<index))]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `np.maximum.accumulate` to transform the array of booleans into most recent previous allowed indexes, and then just lookup the `idx`-th element

first create an array of indexes, set the forbidden positions to 0. `accumulate` returns the rolling application of the function, in this case `maximum`, and `maximum` differs from `max` in that it is applied to two arrays, returning the element-wise max array.

```
lookup = np.arange(len(forbidden))
lookup[forbidden] = 0
lookup = np.maximum.accumulate(lookup)

lookup[13]
# 5
lookup[5]
# 5
lookup[149]
# 136
```

---

to right-shift instead

set the forbidden positions any value greater than or equal to the length of the array, and use `np.minimum.accumulate` on the reversed lookup array. this is basically the same as the left-shift method above.

```
lookup[forbidden] = len(forbidden)
lookup = np.minimum.accumulate(lookup[::-1])[::-1]

lookup[136]
# 136
lookup[137]
# 150
```

Comment: Note that `forbidden[136] == False`, so I'd expect the algorithm to return `136` for the numbers after that -- but it returns `57`

Comment: `cumsum()` works correctly for the first `True` values, but the way it's written it does not add the "skipped" indices at the end of each `True` set.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is there a straight-forward way of moving to the right instead of left?

Comment: how would you handle the index `136` then?

Comment: Change `forbidden[136] = False` and you can rely on the corner value being permitted. I'm interested in standard algorithms and not all the patches one adds for the corner cases.